# Java - Import Base64 lib from command line

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a license generator, follow the code below:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class GerarLicenca{
    static String pass = "abccoss!23167#ms";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        if(args.length > 0){
            if(args[0].equals("encode") && args.length >= 3){
                encode(args);
            }else if(args[0].equals("decode") && args.length >= 2){
                decode(args);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Por favor executar:");
        System.out.println("java GerarLicenca encode 'grails-framework' '10/10/2020 12:00'");
        System.out.println("java GerarLicenca decode 'zlhMh05Op/6xmYhOBcQj0pnVgbA8gqiXP1rIxYhvD4U='");
    }

    static public void encode(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if(!args[1].isEmpty() && !args[2].isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Gerando licença");
            String licText = args[0] + "|"+args[1];
            String encryptedBase64Data = new String(encrypt(licText.getBytes("UTF8")));
            System.out.println("Licença gerada, cpiar abaixo:");
            System.out.println(encryptedBase64Data);
        }else{
            if(args[1].isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Por favor informar app name");
            }
            if(args[2].isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Por favor informar data");
            }
        }
    }

    static public void decode(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if(!args[1].isEmpty()){
            String licText = new String(decrypt(args[1].getBytes("UTF8")));
            String [] info = licText.split("\\|");
            Date maxDate = null;
            String appName = null;
            
            try {
                if (info.length == 2) {
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
                    maxDate =  df.parse(info[1]);
                    appName = info[0];
                    System.out.println("Data: "+maxDate+ " app Name: "+appName);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Erro ao descriptografar");
                }
                
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    static public byte[] getpass() throws Exception{
        return pass.getBytes("UTF8");
    }

    static public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(getpass(), "AES");
        
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] encryptedData = c.doFinal(data);
        return Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedData);
    }
    
    static public byte[] decrypt(byte[] base64EncrypteData) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(getpass(), "AES");

        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] debase64EncryptedData = Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncrypteData);
        return c.doFinal(debase64EncryptedData);
    }
}
```

and I'm compiling from the command line follow the print
[image]

As you can see from the print it gives an error because it is not being able to import the

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

however I downloaded the .jar and it's inside my folder, and I'm going through the command in javac

```
javac -cp commons-codec-1.7.jar:. GenerateLicenca.java
```

but nothing works, can someone give me a light on how to do this, other than by IDE, do it directly from the command line?

Comment: You have to apply the `-cp` switch when you run your program, not just when you compile it. You may find it easier to use the built-in [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class instead.

Comment: Also, you will have one less exception to worry about if you use [`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) instead of `"UTF8"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the classpath when you run your program:

```
java -cp commons-codec-1.7.jar:. GenerateLicenca encode 'grails-framework' '10/10/2020 12:00'
```

Comment: thank you very much it was very obvious and i didn't understand